# Android SDK Fragments -- retain State over multiple activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am developing an application where i have a main activity consisting on the left of a fragment showing products. Depending on the selection, the right part of the landscape-view shows detailed information, where the product's properties can be thoroughly specified. This is the case if the application's running in landscape-mode. If the orientation changes to portrait-mode, then the user first selects a product and then specifies the product's properties by individual dedicated activities, where each activity contains exactly one fragment of the previously mentioned landscape-view.

The problem now comes when I rotate my screen during runtime. Assume that I started the application in portrait mode, and I select the first product (Activity A, Fragment A). The next screen (separate Activity, call it Activity B) will contain a Fragment B where I can specify Property 1 of the product. Now I rotate the screen. The application will then show the landscape-view where the first product is selected, and ALL fragments dedicated to product configuration are shown at the right. Is there a solution that I can retain the configurations done by the user in the separate activity (i.e. Fragment B, Activity B) in such a manner that the land-scape view receives the state such that the details view can properly show the hitherto done configurations?

To summarize:

I am in Activity A, just containing a list of products (Fragment A)
I select the first
then I get to a new Activity B, where Fragment B is shown
then I rotate my screen
then I get back to Activity A, now containing at the left side Fragment A (the list) and at the right side (among others) Fragment B.
I want the state of Fragment B in Activity B be available in Activity A, Fragment B.

Hope I could completely specify my question.

TIA
Gerald

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions that I could think of right now:

1. Forget about 2 Activities in this case, and solve this scenario with only 1. I had multiple projects with exactly these requirements. In portrait mode, I used a ViewSwitcher or a ViewFlipper to show Fragment A or Fragment B full-screen. On landscape, things remain the same you described. This way the 2 fragments can communicate with each other, Fragment B may update the selection on Fragment A.
2. Start Activity B with .startActivityForResult(), so it may supply a result for Activity A, containing the current selection.